# Link Error that built with Bootstrap (newbie)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, gridview, responsive-design

*First off, I'm pretty new to programming field, just right started.*

I got problems with nav links, that works fine in Desktop view. But, it goes **un-clickable in responsive view**.

Please help me. I'm sure this is easy-peasy for you.

Here's the demo: https://zeraus.github.io/brapstoot/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap is a mobile first framework. You established the class for its desktop view but didn't for responsive views.

find the div where the feed goes and add the smaller screen size views classes like this:

```
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
           <div class="visible-xs-block"></div>
           ...
       </div>
```

p.s. don't get discouraged by the down voting and don't stop asking. You are new, you clarified that, so it's normal to make mistakes when you ask. Those downvotes are to protect the integrity of S.O. not to personally to hurt you. You'll get them back as you start posting better. In the meantime, here are some tips:

Never post a link directly to your site. Too many spammers out there. I took a risk. Others won't.

Always post the relevant HTML, CSS, JS or whatever code you have needs attention.

If possible get acquainted with [JFiddle.com](http://JFiddle.com) and [codepen](http://codepen.io/pen/) post your code there and then the link here so that we have an online editor to work with.

don't come asking for broad answers like "How to build a website?" DO your footwork, try something. And then come asking.

And once you can post screenshots, do so.

If your question doesn't get attetion, don't duplicate the same question.

Don't use profanity and dont insult. We're here to help you voluntarily. We don't have to do it, you know lol

Do that on the next question and you will be golden!

Good luck and code something beautiful!

Comment: It works. Thanks! And I really appreciate for your advice. :)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is the most popular `HTML, CSS, and JavaScript` framework for developing responsive, `mobile-first web sites`.
**Try like this**

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
    <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p> 
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Column 3</h3>        
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :)